# FBSDKLoginKit, How does one have a callback for when logging out is complete?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

So, I've read that logging out is done like this: `FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()`

Does Facebook make a network call so their server knows the logout took place? If so, how do I hook into the callback. I've read the docs and see that the logOut function calls `[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil]` and `[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil]`. Does that mean it is just client-side and I don't have to show any UIActivityIndicatorView or that I don't even have to do error handling for logging out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, they simply remove the local access token and any cached data. By looking at the comments of the logout method from the sdk file:

```
/*!
 @abstract Logs the user out
 @discussion This calls [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil]
 and [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil].
 */
- (void)logOut;
```

We as a developer-user have to rely on how they provide the api, and from the this method, it looks like its a local job (client-side), no web service involved. So there's no need to show activity indicator or whatsoever.